# Java Sound dramatically slower after JVM 8 update

Tags: java, performance, audio, jvm, java-8

My Application loads a bunch of audio clips at startup. It uses `java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(URL audioFileURL)` to load the files, which are in the same folder. I could see that this function is basically a wrapper to get `JavaSoundAudioClip` objects

Until yesterday, I compiled the JAR with JDK 7 and launched it with JRE version 7 update 45. Then I updated to version 8 update 31.
Now, the loading of each audio takes ten times longer than before (was 0.2 seconds each, now it is between 2 and 3 seconds)
The same behaviour happened on different hardware configurations. OS is 64bit Windows 7, both Java 7 and 8 runtime environments are 32bit.

Digging deeper in debugging, I found that the methods that slowed down the most are `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream` , `AudioSystem.isLineSupported` , `AudioSystem.getLine`

Audio format shouldn't be involved: I tried both OGG and WAV with the same results.

The settings for both JVMs are the same

EDIT: even I couldn't reproduce the problem in a small program made ad-hoc. Java 8 is slower indeed, but only with a 10% factor. There must be something in particular with my application and the libraries I'm using that is conflicting with audio system and/or its streams. I will update as soon as I find out.

Comment: Could you compare the performance of this method calls between the jdk 7 and 8 : `JDK13Services.getProviders(AudioFileReader.class);
        JDK13Services.getProviders(MixerProvider.class);
        JDK13Services.getProviders(AudioFileReader.class);`

Comment: Are we talking Oracle JDK or for the OpenJDK?

Comment: Do you have a test case demonstrating the problem? I could not reproduce it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I found out what was causing the problem. I used jar-in-jar-loader (as far as I know, it's equivalent to Eclipse option "Package required libraries into generated JAR") to include library jars inside my application. Until now, this never had any noticeable impact on performance.
But with Java 8 I experience this tremendous slowdown. Monitoring the application with jconsole I noticed it was often blocked waiting for zip deflate operations, so something must have changed in JRE version 8, which is now less optimized for jars inside jars.

I resolved choosing to extract all library jars and then packaging them in my application jar.

Comment: Thanks for sharing with us and its an interesting finding. Between I prefer maven-shade-plugin, it unpacks all the classes into a single jar.

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 introduces some new techniques of garbage collectors. 
Since you are loading data/Ojects into the VM, they might be getting triggered to perform concurrent sweeps and parallel compaction. 
Recommend you to tune the JVM GC params.

-XX:ConcGCThreads=n     Number of threads concurrent garbage collectors will use. The default value varies with the platform on which the JVM is running.

-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=n    Percentage of the (entire) heap occupancy to start a concurrent GC cycle. It is used by GCs that trigger a concurrent GC cycle based on the occupancy of the entire heap, not just one of the generations (e.g., G1). A value of 0 denotes 'do constant GC cycles'. The default value is 45.

-XX:ParallelGCThreads=n     Sets the number of threads used during parallel phases of the garbage collectors. The default value varies with the platform on which the JVM is running.
-XX:ConcGCThreads=n     Number of threads concurrent garbage collectors will use. The default value varies with the platform on which the JVM is running.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

> Kindly, let me know if GC tuning helped, I am not able to replicate
>   your scenario, but it would be an interesting fact to learn what was
>   causing it !

Comment: I tried to do some tuning on GC but didn't notice any enhancement. I will update as soon as I discover the cause (and I'd better make it quick cause Java 7 is going to be discontinued in April)